# Can I have Faraday HTTP cache respond with cache when origin is down?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, faraday

Is it possible to have the [faraday-http-cache middleware](https://github.com/plataformatec/faraday-http-cache)  return a cached resource when the origin is down, sort of like what [Cloudflare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168006-How-does-Always-Online-work-) does? I ask because our Rails application is currently doubling as a sort of shared cache for our CMS's REST API and we would like to serve cached content if the CMS goes down.

There was a hack for this posted in a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/plataformatec/faraday-http-cache/issues/84) from 2016. The conversation suggests the use of the `max-stale` cache directive because there were no concrete plans to implement the `stale-if-error` directive from [RFC 5861](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5861). Does anyone know for sure if this still works?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After running some tests, it appears that if the origin domain is non-existent then you will just get a network error, even if dummy data for the fake site is stored in the cache. I had to implement new middleware for recovering from these errors.